# get value of private var in a class through typehinted object to assign it in php 5.3

Tags: php, php-5.3, type-hinting

I have been reading Rafactoring by Martin Fowler and in the beginning of the book he uses an example application (written in Java), which I am trying to convert over to PHP for training purposes. (I have trimmed the code down to make this question, but it works if the variables are public.)

The trouble is to create a statement I need access to a value (see switch) using method getCode() of Movie class since $code is private. (Of course if all of the variables were public the code below would work, but I want to keep them private.)

Can someone please shed some light on how I would access the private variable calling the getCode() method of Movie from the switch in statement(). (Or if there is a better way to do it, let me know.)

```
class Movie {
    private $title;
    private $code;

    public function __construct($title, $code) {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    public function getCode() {
        return $this->code;
    }

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }
}

class Rental {
    private $movie; // will carry a Movie object
    private $days;

    public function __construct(Movie $movie, $days) {
        $this->movie = $movie;
        $this->days = $days;
    }

    public function getMovie() {
        return $this->movie;
    }
}

class Customer {
    private $name;
    private $rentals; // will be a collection of Rental Objects

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function addRental(Rental $rental) {
        $this->rentals[] = $rental;
    }

    public function statement() {
        $thisAmount = 0;

        foreach ($this->rentals as $each) {
            // what is the better way to call this value??????
            switch ($each->movie->code) {
                case 1:
                    $thisAmount+= ($each->days - 2) * 1.5;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    $thisAmount += $each->days * 3;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    $thisAmount += 1.5;
                    break;
            }

            // show figures for this rental
            $result = "\t" . $each->movie->title . "\t" . $thisAmount . "\n";
        }

        return $result;
    }
}

// pick a movie
$movie = new Movie('Star Wars', 0);
// now rent it
$rental = new Rental($movie, '2');

// now get statement
$customer = new Customer('Joe');
$customer->addRental($rental);

echo $customer->statement();
```

Comment: After adding a getTitle() method in Movie I was then able to use the solution provided by @xbonez.  However, to solve all errors I needed to apply it to the switch as well as the building of $result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating over a collection of `movie` in your foreach. So you can do it this way:

```
foreach($this->rentals as $rental) {
   switch($rental->getMovie()->getCode()) {
```

Of course, you can leave your variable named `each`. I just find `$movie` more readable and understandable in this context.

Comment: Yes, I agree with the variable rename and that goes along with the purpose of the code since the overall purpose is to refactor it once it is in a working state.  However, what you are suggesting returns:
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Rental::getCode()

Comment: See edit. I didn't realize rentals was a collection of `rental` objects and not `movie` objects.

Comment: Thanks for looking further. However, I am still getting a Fatal error from PHP. (even after fixing the typo $rantal to be $rental) PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access private property Rental::$movie

Comment: What line are you getting that error at? You're not accessing the private variable in my code snippet so you shouldn't be getting that error.

Comment: AH HA, you are right! Thanks. The error was actually on the line were I was getting the title for the $result.  I had to then create a getTitle() in Movie to do that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

replace your line with just:

```
$each->getMovie->getCode()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and I did a copy/paste of the code as well as your snippet to test my own sanity, and I received:

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access private property Rental::$movie

Comment: @AdamCulp: ahhh ok, movie is private too. I have updated my answer. If this answers you, consider to upvote or mark as the answer

Comment: I hope you can help me on this, and will definetely give credit for it. Sorry, but that didn't do much better. It seems that it is not able to reach getCode() through that method.  PHP returned a Notice and a Fatal error: PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Rental::$getMovie AND PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getCode() on a non-object